# In-order traversal deviating to other locations in memory

Tags: c, pointers, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to do an in-order traversal on a BST. In the first call of `inOrder()` everything works as expected: `*node` points to the root and in the debugger I can see that the whole three is represented correctly (i.e., the root's descendants are correctly represented).

However, in the next call on the left child of the root (i.e., `*node` now represents the root's left child), the tree is not represented correctly anymore. The only things that are correct are the `value` of `*node` and the `right` child being `NULL`. The left child is not the node with the value 3 that was appended before, but it has some weird values - it appears to point at a random memory location.

(If I run further, Xcode terminates saying: EXC_BAD_ACCESS...)

Can you explain me why this is so?

```
#include <stdio.h>


typedef struct Node Node;
struct Node
{
    int value;
    Node *left;
    Node *right;
};

void inOrder(Node *node)
{
    if(node!=NULL)
    {
        inOrder(node->left);
        printf("%d,", node->value);
        inOrder(node->right);
    }
}

void append(Node *root)
{
    Node n = {3,NULL};
    root->left->left = &n;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    Node a = {10, NULL};
    Node b = {5, NULL};
    Node root = {8, &b, &a};

    // appends a node with value 3 to the node 5 (just a test)
    append(&root);

    inOrder(&root);
    puts("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside `append()` function,

```
void append(Node *root)
{
    Node n = {3,NULL};
    root->left->left = &n;
}
```

you're trying to *return* the address of a local variable `n` from the function. Outside `append()`, the address of `n` is invalid. Using that invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

**Solution:** Define `n` as a pointer of type `Node`, allocate memory dynamically using [`malloc()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) and then you can *return* the pointer. The lifetime of dynamically allocated memory remains valid until deallocated.

Comment: Thank you! I see, i should create it outside, and pass it as an argument to be appended!

Comment: Would creating the node inside of append with malloc and appending it cause the same weird behaviour? Or is using malloc equivalent to my way of creating the node?

Comment: @ndrizza `malloc()` is the recommended way to go here, IMHO.

Comment: You mean using malloc inside the append function or outside?

Comment: @ndrizza inside only. as I told, the lifetime of dynamically allocated memory spans untill deallocated manually. So, you can certainly do `Node *n`, allocate using `malloc()` and then `root->left->left = n;`

Comment: Thank you for your explanantion!

Answer (score 1):

```
root->left->left = &n;
```

The variable `n` is local to the function `append()` and once you exit the function `append()` `n` is no more valid.

So accessing the variable out of its scope leads to undefined behavior